# Accessing a value type through delegates

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I have an event in a c# blazor component that fires when I edit a field in my table.  The table is generated through a generalised reporting tool (a component on a page, the report being defined in the component's children on the face of the page), hence the use of generic types.

```
<input type="text" @bind="@editedValue" 
@bind:after="@(()=>HandleEvent(thisValueEditItems[columnNumber],ItemEditedFilter,ItemEdited))" />
```

The event is handled as follows: `

```
private void HandleEvent(List<TEdit> editItems,Func<List<TEdit>,TEdit> itemEditedFilter,Func<TEdit,Object> itemEdited)
    {
        var itemToChange = itemEditedFilter(editItems);
        var itemEd = itemEdited(itemToChange);
        itemEd=editedValue;
    }`
```

editItems is a list of data items, itemEditedFilter selects the single target for the edit, and itemEdited selects the property of the (complex) object TEdit that is to be updated.

I want the edit to alter the underlying item in editItems, but var itemEd seems to be simply a value type object and rather than the reference type I was hoping for and nothing is therefore altered in the parent dataset after the edit.

For completeness, in my test scenario, the delegates are defined as:

```
ItemEditedFilter="@((List<PeriodicMetricDTO> x)=>x.Where(u=>u.Enquiry_id>1000).FirstOrDefault())"
ItemEdited="@((PeriodicMetricDTO x) =>x.cf.JobValue)"
```

The DTO is:

```
 public class PeriodicMetricDTO
    {
        public int Enquiry_id { get; set; }
        public string Project_Name { get; set; }
        public AtomicMetric bf { get; set; }
        public AtomicMetric cf { get; set; }
    }
```

AtomicMetric is:

```
public class AtomicMetric
        {
            public decimal JobValue { get; set; }
            public decimal JobCosts { get; set; }
        }
```

Totally realise this is me reaching the limit of my c# expertise, but my AI chums have drawn a blank!  Which might indicate a more fundamental gap in my knowledge.  Thanks guys.

Comment: Where is `editedValue` coming from? Maybe you could change the `ItemEdited` to `Action<TEdit>` and use it like so: `ItemEdited="@((PeriodicMetricDTO x) =>x.cf.JobValue = editedValue)"`.

Comment: Thanks - editedValue is a value bound to the <input />.  Will add to the question

Comment: editedValue is a value bound to the <input />. So it's part of the component whereas the ItemEdited delegate is defined in the parent page.  So editedValue isn't available to the page.   Have edited question to show this a bit better.

Comment: any chance we can see your value-type's definition? call it a hunch, but I'm guessing that it *really shouldn't be a value-type*; I can't be 100% certain of this (hence the question), but: let's just say that *a lot of the time* people ask about value-types: they're using them wrong. `struct` doesn't mean "a simple object"

Comment: Hi thanks - yes - have added the objects.

Comment: @RichFreeman what's the value-type in there? I see two classes...

Comment: The value-types are the decimals in the AtomicMetric class.  Changing those decimals seems not to update the parent objects (itemEd is pointed to them by virtue of the ItemEdited Func<>)

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this is just a bad idea:

- reflection/data-binding: hates mutable value-types (`object`-typed)
- inbuilt delegate types (`Func<...>`, `Action<...>`): hate mutable value-types (pass-by-value, not `ref`)
- list: hates mutable value-types (no `ref T` accessor unless you go via `CollectionsMarshal`)

To make this work you would need to bypass all of those things, but more importantly:

- best practice: hates mutable value-types (outside of some very niche scenarios)

My advice here is: make your value-type a `readonly struct`, or at least *pretend* that it is a `readonly struct` if it is outside of your control, and don't try to edit them in-place; alternatively, make them `class`.

Comment: ok thank you... so the approach seems pretty flawed all round!  So I'm thinking the  alternative is for me to invoke callbacks from the component containing the <input /> back up the component tree to the parent that owns the data and implement some kind of reflection mechanism to identify then mutate the data where it resides (rather than expecting the refs to make it intact all the way to my child component through the jungle of Func/List etc.).  That was actually my first approach, I'd just thought that trying this might be more elegant when in-fact it's just bad :-)

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a solution - but I'm still super-conscious of the warnings from @Marc Gravell and therefore it feels more like a workaround rather than a solution, and I'm sure there is better out there.

I simply wrapped my value-types (the decimals in AtomicMetric) in a class 'DecimalRef':

```
public class DecimalRef {
   public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

so now I have:

```
public class AtomicMetric
        {
            public DecimalRef JobValue { get; set; }
            public DecimalRef JobCosts { get; set; }
        }
```

Now when I update 'itemEd' (or rather 'itemEd.Value') in my event handler the parent object (ultimately thisValueEditItems[columnNumber] in my Blazor code) is still pointed at the new values - which was the desired behaviour.